# Как сделать проводник файлов в юнити в игре под андроид?

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

Необходима возможность в игре, сделаной на Unity, загрузить изображение .png для последующего использования. При этом, целевой путь изначально неизвестен, и пользователь должен найти файл самостоятельно.
Еще известно, что у разных устройств коренные папки имеют разные названия.

Comment: готового решения из коробки не существует. Возможно есть какие-то платные ассеты. Или просто ищи по "unity choose file from local storage" в гугле

Comment: https://api.unity.com/v1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=asset_store_v2&locale=en_GB&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fassetstore.unity.com%2Fauth%2Fcallback%3Fredirect_to%3D%252Fpackages%252Ftools%252Fgui%252Ffile-chooser-dialog-box-31546&response_type=code&state=0feda2ac-6a53-442d-84a3-bb00b7f53129